# Cobol number to php number

Tags: php, cobol

I know nothing about Cobol but am working with a system that exports numbers to that format.

Here is what I am given:

Format:
9(05)V99

Input:
2380001

Needed Output is a decimal number

Preferable I would like example code in php on how to convert this. I read http://www.pgrocer.net/Cis12/cobol3.html but I don't understand this.

Comment: 9(05)V99 means that the number has 5 whole numbers and 2 decimal places. So, 2380001 is the number 23800.01. All of your input, if properly formatted, should be 7 characters long (left-padded with zeros). If so, just divide each number by 100: $phpnumer = $cobolnumber/100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In COBOL, this represents a number with implied decimal places.  The "V" denotes the location of the decimal point.  In PHP, you would take this value and divide by 100 to get the same value that a COBOL program would use while processing.

Comment: Great thanks. If the format is 9(05)V999 could I divide by 1000 to get the value?

Comment: So 2380001 = 23800.01 (for format 9(05)V99). This seems like a really high price for an item. Could this be done any other way or does this mean it is 5 digits and 2 decimals?

Comment: @BillWoodger It must have been a Y2K error ;) - but seriously, I think you may be onto something with the layout being mismatched.

Comment: I mismatched the parsing! Thanks!

Comment: If you an make that "denotes the position of an implied decimal-point" or similar, and tidy the comments (you too, please, @ChrisMuench) then we'll be good to go. Seems like a Magic Trick. Divded by 100 to get the number you first thought of :-)